# Send an animation with an email

Tags: email, animation

We have been asked to write a simple animation to send to clients via email, for Xmas. :)

Without requiring people to download stuff, to go to a webpage etc. I guess the only option is to have an animated gif.

We were hoping first to embed some javascript animation, but this is probably moot due to security restrictions in email clients etc.

Can someone think of any other option?

Comment: GIF, is it that bad to redirect to a web page?

Comment: @FruityP: from our point of view (developers) not so much, but it's known that there will be much less people actually clicking on and visiting that link...so the person actually requesting this would rather like to avoid this. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 options:

1. [Animated GIF](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/3682/animated-gif-support-in-email/). This is by far the most supported option. It defaults to the first frame of the animation in clients where it is not supported (Outlook 07, 10 and Windows Mobile).
2. [HTML5 video](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/2905/html5-and-video-in-email/). This is supported in Mac clients only. You can set a fallback image for all other clients where it is unsupported.
3. [CSS Animations](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/the-state-of-css3-in-email-templates/). They are only supported in Mac clients.

Mac clients have the best support because they use the Webkit render engine.

Unfortunately there is no method that offers 100% compatibility across major email clients without redirecting them to a web page to view the animation.